# Check if field exists in for function PHP

Tags: php

I have this PHP script:

```
for ($desc=1; $_POST['ddata'.$desc]; $desc++) { 
    if($_POST['ddata'.$desc]){
        if ($desc == 1){
            $ddata = $_POST['ddata'.$desc];
            $dlocatie = $_POST['dlocatie'.$desc];
        } else {
            $ddata = $ddata.' / '.$_POST['ddata'.$desc];
            $dlocatie = $dlocatie.' / '.$_POST['dlocatie'.$desc];
        }
    }
}
```

If I have 5 `ddata` fields, it gives this error: `Undefined index: ddata6`

How can I check if that fields exists so I can prevent this error?

Comment: Is `$desc` 0 - 4 or 1 - 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check if that fields exists so I can prevent this error?

use `isset()` to check if item exists prior accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if($_POST['ddata'.$desc])`, you can do:

```
if(isset($_POST['ddata'.$desc]))
```

Or:

```
if(array_key_exists('ddata'.$desc, $_POST))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for

```
if(isset($_POST['thekey']))
```

or more traditionally:

```
if(array_key_exists('thekey', $_POST))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 isset($_POST['ddata'.$desc])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for what fields exist BEFORE you do your loop, by using preg_grep to scan the array for your `ddata...` fields.

```
$ddata_fields = preg_grep('/^ddata\d+$/', array_keys($_POST));
foreach($ddata_fields as $field) {
    $ddata = $_POST[$field];
    etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `if(isset($_POST['ddata'.$desc])){}` instead of `if($_POST['ddata'.$desc]){}`

Answer (score 0):

Change the section beginning with...

```
if($_POST['ddata'.$desc]){
```

To....

```
for ($desc=1; $_POST['ddata'.$desc]; $desc++) { 
    if (isset($_POST['ddata'.$desc])) {
        $ddata = $_POST['ddata'.$desc'];
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    switch($desc) {
    case "1" :
        $ddata = $_POST['ddata'.$desc];
        $dlocatie = $_POST['dlocatie'.$desc];
    break;
    case "2" :
    case "3" :
    case "4" :
    case "5" :
        $ddata = $ddata.' / '.$_POST['ddata'.$desc];
        $dlocatie = $dlocatie.' / '.$_POST['dlocatie'.$desc];
    break;
    }
}
```